# Two ways to interpret $Q = A\cos\phi + \sqrt{A^2\cos^2\phi}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've run into an unexpected problem regarding the following equation:

$$Q = A\cos\phi + \sqrt{A^2\cos^2\phi}$$

A is always a positive number.  My first inclination is to just simplify the eqn as,

$$Q = 2A\cos\phi $$

However, I get two different answers if $\cos\phi$ is negative (i.e. if $\phi$ is equal to 180 degrees, for example).

If $\cos\phi = -1$, from Eqn. 1, I would get the following:

$$Q = A(-1) + \sqrt{A^2(-1)^2} = -A + A = 0$$

But from the second equation I would get

$$Q = 2A(-1) = -2A$$

Not sure what to do about this. From what I'm doing, I believe Eqn 1 is the way it needs to work, but how do I discount Eqn. 2?

Comment: If $\cos(\phi)\lt0$, then $\sqrt{\cos^2(\phi)}=-\cos(\phi)$

Comment: In general, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, so you have to take the sign of the radicand into account.

Comment: So does that mean the following if $\cos\phi < 0$ (assume $\cos\phi = -1$),

$$Q = A(-1) + (-A) = -2A$$

Comment: For one range of values of $\phi$ one equation defines the relationship and for a different range of values, a different equation defines the relationship.  What is the problem with that?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand it.... Again, based on what Tanner and Taladris posted, it would seem that $Q = -2A$ for $\phi = 180$ degrees.  And if $\phi = 0$ degrees then $Q = 2A$.  Is that correct?

Comment: For $\phi=180^\circ$, $Q=0$

Comment: @Tanner.  Thanks for the response, but could you show me how you are getting that.  If $\phi = 180^o$, then $\cos\phi = -1$.  But -1 has to be used in both terms of the first equation, doesn't it?  So you get - A + -A = -2A. Or are you saying based on your first answer, which was $-\cos\phi$, that it is actually $-(-1)$???

Comment: When $\phi=180^\circ$, $Q=A\cos\phi+\sqrt{A^2\cos^2(\phi)}=A(-1)+\sqrt{A^2(-1)^2}=-A+A=0$

Comment: Yes.  That is the first solution I posted.  So, when I actually provide the mathematical solution, I should not simplify as I showed in the original post in Eq. 2.  I should leave it as it is in Eq. 1 even though the temptation is to simplify as shown in Eq. 2.  Is that correct?

Comment: Just read the first two comments, and then read them again, and again, until you understand what they are saying. They tell you all you need to know, provided you make the effort to understand them.

Comment: The second equation ($Q=2A\cos\phi$) is not valid when $\cos\phi<0$; when $\cos\phi<0$, $Q=A\cos\phi\color{blue}-A\cos\phi=0$

Comment: Thanks, Gerry. In your world condescending comments are always helpful.

Comment: Sorry, rdemo, you got two good answers in those comments, and instead of stopping to think about them, you went bumbling on, getting things wrong. In my world, when repeated, patient, simple and correct comments don't seem to be helping, I try something else.

Answer (score 1):

In general, we can write $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, thus, in this case, $\sqrt{A^2\cos^2{\phi}}=|A\cos{\phi}|.$
Our expression simplifies to:
$$
A\cos{\phi}+|A\cos{\phi}|.
$$
From the properties of the absolute value function, we know $|x|=x$, if $x\ge 0$ and $|x|=-x$,if $x<0$. Thus we can conclude, $A\cos{\phi}+|A\cos{\phi}|=2A\cos{\phi}$, if $\cos{\phi}\ge 0$, and $A\cos{\phi}+|A\cos{\phi}|=0$, if $\cos{\phi}<0$.